# Test coverage in django - No module named django_test_coverage.runner

Tags: django, django-testing

I installed **django_test_coverage** by *easy install* and simply added the line

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'django_test_coverage.runner.CoverageTestSuiteRunner'
```

to my settings (Django 1.4)

But when I run the test with

> python manage.py test myapp

I am getting:

**ImportError: No module named django_test_coverage.runner**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package on PyPi is broken. You cannot install this with `easy_install` or `pip`.
https://github.com/srosro/django-test-coverage/issues/7

It works if you install from source:

```
git clone git://github.com/srosro/django-test-coverage.git
cd django-test-coverage
python setup.py install
```